# Php script in html run locally with Apache

Tags: php, html

I'm using Apache 2.2 on windows 7 to play a little with php5 code (locally via http://localhost/).
The php is installed as apache 2.2 module.

 Problem is, that php code works great (for example, `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in `index.php` file),

 and html code also works (`<html><body>Hi!</body></html>` in `index.html`), but 
php script in html doesn't work (`<html><body><?php phpinfo(); ?></body></html>` in `index.html`).

What am I missing in the cofiguration file for running php script in html pages, locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your apache configuration:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name files that have php code in them as .php otherwise apache won't parse the code.

For example:

```
<html><body><?php phpinfo(); ?></body></html>
```

Needs to be named

```
index.php
```

You do not need to name the files .html just because it's html in the file, but if there are php code you have to name the file .php.

Answer (score -1):

If you're putting php code in it, you have to call it index.php, not index.html.

Comment: not necessarily. You can tell your web server to process files with a .html extension as PHP files. See @Ken's answer for how to do this in Apache.

Comment: It depends on your setup. I like a more granular approach than automatically treating all html files with whatever PHP handler you're using (mod_php, cgi, etc.)